# ¿Por que no manda los datos de mi codigo de java a bases de datos access, me aparece "los datos no han sido guardados correctamente?

Tags: java, netbeans, .htaccess, netbeans-8.2, javacc

Hola tengo un proyectos conectar netbeans java a bases de datos acces e estado viendo varios codigos pero me salen varios problemas uno de ellos esque no guarda los datos y no se mandan a mi base de datos acces[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
al igual quiero que el campo "id alimentos" este bloqueado ya que ese campo debe ser auto numerico es decir que no pueda modificarlo pero no funciona todos los codigos que e intenado alguna recomendacion aqui dejo todo mi codigo
`

```
DefaultTableModel mt = new DefaultTableModel();


public Alimentos() {
    initComponents();
    
    String ids [] ={"Id_alimento","marca","tp_alimento","pz_existentes","contenido","precio"};
    mt.setColumnIdentifiers(ids);
    tablainfo.setModel(mt);
    
    nuevo.setEnabled(true);
    guardar.setEnabled(false);
    editar.setEnabled(false);
    eliminar.setEnabled(false);
    limpiar();
    habilitar();
    desabilitar();
    vaciarTabla();
    verDatos();
}
 public void desabilitar(){
    idalimentos.setEnabled(false);
    marca.setEnabled(false);
    tpalimento.setEnabled(false);
    precio.setEnabled(false);
    cdproducto.setEnabled(false);
    contenido.setEnabled(false);
}

public void habilitar(){
    idalimentos.setEnabled(true);
    marca.setEnabled(true);
    tpalimento.setEnabled(true);
    precio.setEnabled(true);
    cdproducto.setEnabled(true);
    contenido.setEnabled(true);
}

public void limpiar(){
    idalimentos.setText("");
    marca.setText("");
    tpalimento.setText("");
    precio.setText("");
    cdproducto.setText("");
    contenido.setText("");

}

    public void vaciarTabla(){
    DefaultTableModel Modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablainfo.getModel();
    String titulos[] = {"ID_ALIMENTO","MARCA","TP_ALIMENTO","PZ_EXISTENTES","CONTENIDO","PRECIO"};
    Modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null,titulos);
    tablainfo.setModel(Modelo);
}


public void verDatos(){
    try {
        Connection con1 = null;
        DefaultTableModel miModelo = (DefaultTableModel) tablainfo.getModel();
        Conexion conect1 = new Conexion();
        con1 = conect1.getConnection();
        String dts[] = new String[5];
        String sql = "select * from alimentos";
        Statement st = con1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            dts[0] = rs.getString("Id_alimento");
            dts[1] = rs.getString("marca");
            dts[2] = rs.getString("tp_alimento");
            dts[3] = rs.getString("pz_existentes");
            dts[4] = rs.getString("contenido");
            dts[5] = rs.getString("precio");
            miModelo.addRow(dts);
        }
        tablainfo.setModel(miModelo);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO SE PUEDEN VISUALIZAR LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    idalimentos = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    eliminar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    marca = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    tpalimento = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    precio = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    cdproducto = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    contenido = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    nuevo = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    editar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    guardar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tablainfo = new javax.swing.JTable();

    eliminar.setText("ELIMINAR");
    eliminar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            eliminarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    marca.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            marcaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    marca.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            marcaKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    tpalimento.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tpalimentoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    tpalimento.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            tpalimentoKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    precio.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            precioActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    precio.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            precioKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    cdproducto.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cdproductoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    cdproducto.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            cdproductoKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("ID ALIMENTOS");

    contenido.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            contenidoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    contenido.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            contenidoKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("MARCA");

    jLabel3.setText("TP ALIMENTO");

    jLabel4.setText("PZ_EXISTENCIA");

    nuevo.setText("NUEVO");
    nuevo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nuevoActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel5.setText("CONTENIDO");

    editar.setText("EDITAR");
    editar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            editarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel6.setText("PRECIO");

    guardar.setText("GUARDAR");
    guardar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            guardarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    tablainfo.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "ID", "MARCA", "TPALIMENTO", "PZ_EXISTENTES", "CONTENIDO", "PRECIO"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false, true, true
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    tablainfo.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            tablainfoMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablainfo);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(idalimentos)
                .addComponent(marca)
                .addComponent(tpalimento)
                .addComponent(precio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 191, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(cdproducto)
                .addComponent(contenido))
            .addGap(39, 39, 39)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(editar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(nuevo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(44, 44, 44)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(eliminar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(guardar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 87, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 727, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 19, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(idalimentos, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(marca, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(guardar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(nuevo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(precio, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(editar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(eliminar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addComponent(tpalimento, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(cdproducto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(contenido, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 304, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void marcaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
   marca.transferFocus();
}                                     

private void tpalimentoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
   tpalimento.transferFocus();
}                                          

private void precioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    precio.transferFocus();
}                                      

private void cdproductoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    cdproducto.transferFocus();
}                                          

private void contenidoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    contenido.transferFocus();
}                                         

private void marcaKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                               
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
    {
        String cad = (""+c).toUpperCase();
        c = cad.charAt(0);
        evt.setKeyChar(c);
    }
}                              

private void tpalimentoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
    {
        String cad = (""+c).toUpperCase();
        c = cad.charAt(0);
        evt.setKeyChar(c);
    }
}                                   

private void precioKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
    {
        String cad = (""+c).toUpperCase();
        c = cad.charAt(0);
        evt.setKeyChar(c);
    }
}                               

private void cdproductoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
    {
        String cad = (""+c).toUpperCase();
        c = cad.charAt(0);
        evt.setKeyChar(c);
    }
}                                   

private void contenidoKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    if(Character.isLowerCase(c))
    {
        String cad = (""+c).toUpperCase();
        c = cad.charAt(0);
        evt.setKeyChar(c);
    }
}                                  

private void eliminarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   int fila = tablainfo.getSelectedRow();
    if (fila == -1)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DEBE SELECCIONAR UN REGISTRO", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    else
    {
        int opc = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "¿ESTA SEGURO QUE DESEA ELIMINAR ESTE REGISTRO?", "Pregunta", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (opc == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {
            try
            {
                Connection con = null;
                Conexion conect = new Conexion();
                con = conect.getConnection();
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                String sql = "delete from alimentos where Id_alimentos = ?";
                PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(idalimentos.getText()));
                int n = pst.executeUpdate();
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "DATOS ELIMINADOS CORRECTAMENTE");
                    limpiar();
                    vaciarTabla();
                    verDatos();
                    nuevo.setEnabled(true);
                    guardar.setEnabled(false);
                    editar.setEnabled(false);
                    eliminar.setEnabled(false);
                    desabilitar();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "DATOS NO ELIMINADOS CORRECTAMENTE" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}                                        

private void editarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try
    {
        Connection con = null;
        Conexion conect = new Conexion();
        con = conect.getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "update alimentos set marca = ?, tp_alimento = ?, pz_existentes = ?, contenido = ?, precio = ? where Id_alimentos = ?";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, marca.getText());
        pst.setString(2, tpalimento.getText());
        pst.setString(3, precio.getText());
        pst.setString(4, cdproducto.getText());
        pst.setString(5, contenido.getText());
        pst.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(idalimentos.getText()));
        int n = pst.executeUpdate();
        if (n > 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "DATOS ACTUALIZADOS CORRECTAMENTE");
            limpiar();
            vaciarTabla();
            verDatos();
            nuevo.setEnabled(true);
            guardar.setEnabled(false);
            editar.setEnabled(false);
            eliminar.setEnabled(false);
            desabilitar();
        }
    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "LOS DATOS NO HAN SIDO ACTUALIZADOS CORRECTAMENTE", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }                                         
}                                      

private void guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   if (marca.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FALTA INGRESAR LA MARCA", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        marca.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (tpalimento.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FALTA INGRESAR  EL TIPO DE ALIMENTO ", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        tpalimento.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (precio.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FALTA INGRESAR LAS PIEZAS EXISTENTES", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        precio.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (cdproducto.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FALTA INGRESAR EL CONTENIDO", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        cdproducto.requestFocus();
    }
    else if (contenido.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "FALTA INGRESAR EL PRECIO", "Advertencia", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        contenido.requestFocus();
    }
    else
    {
        
        try
        {
            Connection con = null;
            Conexion conect = new Conexion();
            con = conect.getConnection();
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "insert into alimentos (marca,tp_alimento,pz_existentes,contenido,precio) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, marca.getText());
            pst.setString(2, tpalimento.getText());
            pst.setString(3, precio.getText());
            pst.setString(4, cdproducto.getText());
            pst.setString(5, contenido.getText());
            int n = pst.executeUpdate();
            if (n > 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "DATOS GUARDADOS CORRECTAMENTE");
                limpiar();
                vaciarTabla();
                verDatos();
                nuevo.setEnabled(true);
                guardar.setEnabled(false);
                editar.setEnabled(false);
                eliminar.setEnabled(false);
                editar.setEnabled(false);
                desabilitar();
            }
        } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "LOS DATOS NO HAN SIDO GUARDADOS CORRECTAMENTE", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}                                       

private void nuevoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
   limpiar();
    habilitar();
    nuevo.setEnabled(false);
    guardar.setEnabled(true);
    editar.setEnabled(false);
    eliminar.setEnabled(false);
    vaciarTabla();
    verDatos();
}                                     

private void tablainfoMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    try
    {
        int fila = tablainfo.getSelectedRow();
        idalimentos.setText(tablainfo.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
        marca.setText(tablainfo.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
        tpalimento.setText(tablainfo.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString());
        precio.setText(tablainfo.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString());
        cdproducto.setText(tablainfo.getValueAt(fila, 4).toString());
        contenido.setText(tablainfo.getValueAt(fila, 5).toString());
        nuevo.setEnabled(false);
        guardar.setEnabled(false);
        editar.setEnabled(true);
        eliminar.setEnabled(true);
        habilitar();
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR AL SELECCIONAR UN EQUIPO : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}                                      


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField cdproducto;
private javax.swing.JTextField contenido;
private javax.swing.JButton editar;
private javax.swing.JButton eliminar;
private javax.swing.JButton guardar;
private javax.swing.JTextField idalimentos;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextField marca;
private javax.swing.JButton nuevo;
private javax.swing.JTextField precio;
public static javax.swing.JTable tablainfo;
private javax.swing.JTextField tpalimento;
// End of variables declaration
```

}
`
por favor indiquenme donde posiblemente tenga error o recomiendenme otro codigo este codigo que adjunte es el campo que debe manda la informacion a acces nose si tambien tengo que poner ek coigo de la conexion que hice ayuda por favor
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYXuY.png

Comment: MUY, MUUUUUY mala costumbre esa de añadir un catch y **ocultar** el error real con un mensaje bonito. Luego pasan cosas y no sabes por qué. Y cómo vamos a poder ayudarte si el único mensaje de error que tenemos es el que nos has puesto tú, muy bonito y muy inútil? Hazte un favor, cuando uses try/catch como mínimo loguea la excepción... si no, nunca sabrás qué está pasando. Hazlo, mira el error real, búscalo en google y si tienes dudas preguntas aquí. Pero usa el error real por favor, nunca lo ocultes sin más, no sirve de nada!